# Does the Nagano-Sussmann orbit theorem--typically stated for real manifolds, as it is used in optimal control--continue to hold for complex manifolds?

Tags: manifolds, control-theory

The [Nagano-Sussmann theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbit_(control_theory)) states that, given a point $x_{0}$ on a real manifold $M$, and a Lie algebra $L$ generated by a family ${\cal F}$ of smooth vector fields on $M$, the *orbit* ${\cal O}_{x_{0}}$ of $x_{0}$ under the action of $L$ is an immersed submanifold of $M$.  It would seem that the answer is Yes, as the proof for the real case seems to admit a complex counterpart in a straightforward fashion, at least for vector fields smooth enough over the complex field.  But, I just wanted to double-check: might I be missing something?